# After pip successful install: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip

I'll go directly to the point. I used

```bsh
pip3 install Pyside2
```

And get this,

```bsh
Requirement already satisfied: Pyside2 in /home/foobar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (5.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: shiboken2==5.14.2 in /home/foobar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Pyside2) (5.14.2)
```

But then  when I try to run this code

```py
import sys

from Pyside2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello World!")
        self.setGeometry(400,400)


myAppy = QApplication(sys.argv)
vent = Window()
vent.show()

myAppy.exec_()
sys.exit(0)
```

With

```bsh
python3 test.py
```

I get this

```bsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Pyside2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pyside2'
```

```py
print(sys.executable)
```

Shows this

```bsh
/home/foobar/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

And I went down to

```bsh
/home/foobar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Pyside2
```

To check if Pyside2 is actually there, and it is. I don't know what else to check or do. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure, but it's possible that you can't use `pip install Pyside2` because Python only excepts `pip install PySide2` (Notice the difference in capitalization). Try uninstalling Pyside2 and running `pip install PySide2`.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Do you know what's the difference between Pyside2 and PySide2?

Comment: they aren't actually separate modules, so Python is just really picky about capitals. :c